# Losing aspect ratio on re-size of window

Tags: html, css

I have a `DIV` re sizing issue

This is my initial screen

[image]

and on dragging the window smaller, I gradualy lose sight of the picture at the bottom

It is re-sizing on resize, but just not at the same ratio.

[image]

```
#logoContainer{
    height: 70vh;
}
.LogoBottom{
    padding-left: 10px;
    content:url("../images/menuNameLogo.png");
}
```

This is what I was using. Why is it losing the aspect-ratio when re sizing smaller?
It is re-sizing, but just not at the same ratio

**Possible Solution with JQuery**

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {

    var height = 0;
    height = $( window ).height();
    $("#logoName").css("height",height);

});
```

**CSS amendment**

```
.LogoBottom{
    padding-left: 10px;
    content:url("../images/menuNameLogo.png");
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 3px;
}
```

Comment: can you put up a jsfiddle to demonstrate? be easier to help if we can play too.

Comment: Need more code. What is the size of the things before #logoContainer?

Comment: Are you creating sidemenu, and you are you maybe using bootstrap?

Comment: @NenadVracar Yes Im using bootstrap

Comment: Have you tried class="img-responsive" on your logo?

Comment: Could be the height of your horizontal bar is greater than 30vh on resize therefore the page size is greater than 100vh resulting in your image being clipped.

Comment: @otherDewi, yeah You could be right. I will check that, thanks

Comment: To the "Close" voters . "Off Toppic"???? - Grab a cup of coffee and wake the f up. The resize was not keeping the aspect ratio, as explained. HOW is that off topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    var height = 0;
    height = $( window ).height();
    $("#logoName").css("height",height);
});
```

**CSS amendment**

```
.LogoBottom{
    padding-left: 10px;
    content:url("../images/menuNameLogo.png");
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 3px;
}
```